# Select input type not working. Suspect Initialize but I've checked the code multiple times

Tags: html, materialize

I'm using Materialize 1.0 and can not get the select input type to work. Nothing shows below the label. I believe I have the initialize correct as I copy and pasted from their website.

I'm following a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxdCIbeO4Uk and can't seem to produce the same result as the author Amit Agarwal. He finished the section I'm having issues with at 17:00 min into the tutorial. The select/option input field is not working. He is using Materialize 1.0. I've checked the code at least 10 times for syntax errors and everything works but the select.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('select').formSelect();
    });

    function sendEmail(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = {
        from: $('#from').val(),
        to: $('#to').val(),
        subject: $('#subject').val(),
        body: $('#body').val();
      };
      alert("You just submitted: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    };
  </script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <h4 class="light"> Mailman </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form onsubmit="sendEmail(event)">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select name="from" id="from">
          <option value="email1">email1@g.com</option>
          <option value="email2">email2@g.com</option>
        </select>
        <label for="from"> Sender Email Address</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter email here" id="to">
        <label for="to" Recipient's Email Address></label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter subject" id="subject">
        <label for="subject" Subject Line></label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <textarea id="body" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
        <label for="body" Email Body></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <button type="submit">Send Email</button> </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</html>
```

I expect to see a dropdown selector.

Comment: Rather than basing your question on content that is inside a video. You should ask about what you are having trouble with and use the video as a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes here in your code
First: You have declared container div outside body tag.
Second: Remove the semi colon  from "body: $('#body').val();" and run the script. It will work.

Comment: Sure enough that was it!  Interesting that the video tutorial has it outside the body tag and it shows it to be working. I guess it wasn't a truly live demonstration and a composite edited video.